# Launch an installed program using Ppython

Tags: python

I have been working working on an app that launches an installed program using python. I do not want to reinstall the file each time i start my app as mentioned below

```
import os
os.startfile('C://Users//Downloads//npp.7.5.6.Installer.exe')
```

I just want to launch the installed one in the C: directory 
Do i have to search the file from the C: directory and then launch it ? or is there an easier way to do that ?

---

```
def locate(pattern, pathpattern="*", root=os.curdir):
    '''Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below
    supplied root directory.'''
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(path, pathpattern):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
                yield os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Comment: Does your app install the program and then launch it, or does it launch a program that was already installed? In either case, you shouldn't call the installer - you should call the NPP executable that was created by the installer (a common location is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"`, but this depends on where you installed the program to).

Comment: My app intends to install the program first and close it, then later on aims to launch it. there are some processes in between

Comment: Ok, then if your app is controlling the installer, you should know where it creates the executable. If you don't alter the installation location, I think it installs by default under `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`. However, if the installation goes well, there should be an `NPP_DIRECTORY` environment variable that contains the directory NPP was installed to, meaning that you can find the executable at `%NPP_DIRECTORY%\notepad++.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use env

```
env
#{'TERM_PROGRAM': 'Apple_Terminal',
# 'SHELL': '/bin/bash',
# etc
```

to see if it has installed any new environment variables after you install the program. You may need to exit python and reenter to see if there is a new variable with the install. Otherwise you have to find it the old fashioned way in ProgramFiles or the windows icon properties